# Limit to infinity of:

Tags: limits

I have this limit that I tried and failed to solve: 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2-n+2}-n}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac1n+\frac{2}{n^2})}-n}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n\times\sqrt{1-\frac1n+\frac{2}{n^2}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=\infty\times0$$

My solution is undefined and I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you mean to convert $-n$ into $-1$?

Comment: I think that your answer is correct. The numerator is clearly of order n and the denominator is just as clearly of order 1. That implies that the limit as n goes to infinity is infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\sqrt{n^2-n+2}-n=\frac{(n^2-n+2)-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2-n+2}+n}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is of the form $\infty - \infty$: that tells you that you need a better approximation. More precisely, it looks like $(n + \text{ smaller stuff}) - n$, and you need to cancel out the most significant terms.

The simplest more precise approximation you can use is the differential approximation:

$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + d(x)(x-a)$$

where

$$ \lim_{x \to a} d(x) = 0 $$

or maybe it's easier for you to think in terms of the mean value theorem

$$ f(x) = f(a) + f'(c) (x-a) $$

for some $c \in [a,x]$.

With luck, whatever is leftover can be easily handled. (or, you can just take an even better approximation, such as a degree $2$ Taylor series)

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the different pieces of the expression $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2-n+2}-n}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac1n+\frac{2}{n^2})}-n}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=n\frac{\sqrt{1-(\frac1n-\frac{2}{n^2})}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=n \frac AB$$ and now use the fact that for small values of $x$, $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ In the numerator, replace $x$ by $(-\frac1n+\frac{2}{n^2})$ and in the denominator replave $x$ by $\frac1n$. After expansion and simplification, the numerator is $$A=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{7}{8 n^2}+\frac{7}{16
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)-1=-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{7}{8 n^2}+\frac{7}{16
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$ and the denominator is $$B=1+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{16
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$ and, so, $$n \frac AB=n\frac{-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{7}{8 n^2}+\frac{7}{16
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)}{1+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{16
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)}$$ Performing the long division, you should arrive to $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2-n+2}-n}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}} \approx -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{8 n}-\frac{3}{16
   n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right)$$ which not only shows the limit but also how it is approached.